# What are the exact files in /system folder used to start internet connection on Android Lollipop?

Tags: custom-roms, internet, mobile-data, data-connection

I need this info to fix internet in a ROM by me.
**I can turn on data but the speed meter always shown 0.10-0.50 kbps,**
Nothing works. I thought it's a DNS problem & **did a ping to google's ip address but failed to connect again**.
I did replaced apns-conf.xml in /system/etc/, changed apn settings but failed.
Then i changed all binaries with net* in /bin/ & their corresponding libraries from /lib/ from stock rom which results :

```
ping 216.58.220.174
PING 216.58.220.174 (216.58.220.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

& then it stopped.
Thanks in Advance.